# How do I get just one category from WP_Query - post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a specific type of category that I have created using Custom Post Types. I have a post type called 'course_downloads' containing a couple of different categories, 'files' and 'images'.

Im using the code below to get the posts but it still displays both categories.

Is there a way to just get the category 'files'?

```
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course_downloads', 'orderby' => 'files', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('course_downloads'),
    'category_name' => 'files',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Or this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course_downloads', 'category_name' => 'files', 'order' => 'ASC') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tax_query instead.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'course_downloads',
    'meta_key' => 'files',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'files',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In `'taxonomy' => 'people',` instead of `'people'` use your taxonomy name. You  can check it from the back-end by visiting the category listing page for course_downloads custom post type in the URL.